# When do instance init blocks get called?

Tags: java

Consider this code:

```
public class Main {


 static String s = "-";

 public static void main (String [] args){

     go();
     System.out.println(s);

     Main m = new Main();
 }
 {go();}

 static {go();}
 static void go(){s+="s";}
}
```

Its output is:

```
-ss
```

the instance init block is never called, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called - AFTER you've printed `s`. Instance initializers are called when instances are created.

Comment: If you're all just going to say the same thing, up-vote the person that said it first and then just add a comment.

Add another "System.out.println(s);" to the very end of your "main" block and you'll see "-sss" as the output.

Answer (score 1):

It is called. However it is called after the call to println because you create the first instance of Main of that. If you move the call to println to the end of main, you'll see three s.

Answer (score 1):

Instance initialization block code runs right after the call to super() in a constructor, in other words, after all super constructors have run.

The order in which initialization blocks appear in a class matters. If a class has more than one they all run in the order they appear in the class file.

Some rules to remember:

1. List item Initialization blocks execute in the order they appear.
2. Static Initialization blocks run once when the class is first
   loaded.
3. Instance Initialization blocks run every time a class
   instance is created.
4. Instance Initialization blocks run after the
   constructor’s call to super().

Answer (score 0):

It is called, but after you print to the console. You aren't making an instance of it until after printing.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have pointed out, the instance init block is called, but it doesnt affect the output of your `System.out.println` statement, because it is called in conjunction with the invocation of the instance of your class: `Main m = new Main();`

One thing you could do when trying to debug these cases is to dump a thread stack at the invocation point:

```
static void go() {
    new Exception().printStackTrace(System.out);
        s += "s";
}
```

This will allow you to see all the times that the `go` method is called, and by using the same print stream as your `println` in your `main` method, you can see the stacks in relation to the output of your `s` var.

In my version, the result looks like this:

```
java.lang.Exception
    at Main.go(Main.java:29)
    at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:25)
java.lang.Exception
    at Main.go(Main.java:29)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
-ss
java.lang.Exception
    at Main.go(Main.java:29)
    at Main.<init>(Main.java:21)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```